# Replacing all occurrences of a value in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I replace, for example, all "-sh2", in a column (V2) with -100, as in the following dataframe:

```
V1  V2  V3
p1  -sh2    13
p2  23  29
p3  17  25
p4  -sh2    34
```

Thanks

Comment: Start by reading this [**basic introductory text on vectors and assignment**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dat$V2 <- replace(as.character(dat$V2), dat$V2 == "-sh2", "-100")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. You can use the `replace` solution above. Or use `ifelse`. Or even:

```
my.df$V2[my.df$V2 == "-sh2"] <- -100
```

Comment: Many thanks Simon, Sven and rrs for the perfect solutions.